# Добавление перевода поля в opencart

Tags: opencart

В opencart 1.5 есть сторонний шаблон купленный shopstore 2, во вкладке Настройка шаблона есть вкладка Контакты и доп. информация, где можно редактировать соответствующие поля. Так вот, у некоторых полей есть два варианта редактирования - для русской версии сайта и для английской, а у некоторых только один вариант, для русского. Как мне добавить для таких полей вариант для английской версии сайта? Пробовал в language / en-gb / en-gb.php дописывать к переменным строки, к примеру: $_['storeset_cont_deliv']  = 'Free for RF'; Ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 1):

> а у некоторых только один вариант, для русского.

Вам необходимо убедиться, что в шаблоне текст добавлен "в виде переменной", а не просто русским текстом. Если там сделано переменной, которая выгружается из языкового файла, то вариант с добавлением в en будет работать.

Если нет: то вам необходимо в оба языковых файла добавить нужные строки, потом их с помощью контроллера передать в файл шаблона и уже там вывести его.